Date & Long Number Issues in Laravel Import With Laravel Excel
I have some data to Import With Laravel Excel and want to store it like input.
Input:
date_of_registration :`2074-08-15`
& bank_account_no: `6013820134824000000`

AllowanceImport Class Model Function like below:
   public function model(array $row)
        {
            return new Allowance([
                    'date_of_registration' => isset($row['date_of_registration'])?$row['date_of_registration']:'',
                    'bank_account_no'  => isset($row['bank_account_no'])?$row['bank_account_no']:'',
                ]);
        }

but the problem comes after importing. the date is shown as a string and the number in scientific notation. data show like this:
Output:
date_of_registration : 63781
bank_account_no : 6.013820134824E+18

Need Like Input:
date_of_registration :`2074-08-15`
& bank_account_no: `6013820134824000000`


The issue you're facing with Laravel Excel is related to how it handles dates and large numbers during import. Here's how you can address it to match your desired output format:
1. Formatting Dates:
By default, Laravel Excel reads dates from Excel files as timestamps. To convert them to your preferred format (YYYY-MM-DD), you can use PHP's Carbon class within your model function.
Here's the updated code:
public function model(array $row)
{
    if (isset($row['date_of_registration'])) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($row['date_of_registration']);
        $row['date_of_registration'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    return new Allowance($row);
}

This code checks if the date_of_registration key exists in the row data. If it does, it uses Carbon to parse the value and then formats it according to your desired format (Y-m-d).
2. Handling Large Numbers:
Large numbers from Excel can be imported in scientific notation by Laravel Excel. To prevent this, you can explicitly cast the value to a string within your model function.
Here's the updated code:
public function model(array $row)
{
    if (isset($row['bank_account_no'])) {
        $row['bank_account_no'] = (string) $row['bank_account_no'];
    }

    // ... rest of your code
}

This code checks if the bank_account_no key exists and then casts the value to a string. This ensures it's treated as a string and not converted to scientific notation.
Remember:

Make sure you have Carbon installed using Composer: composer require carbon/carbon
These changes modify the data before creating a new Allowance instance.

By implementing these adjustments, your imported data should match the desired format with correctly formatted dates and string values for large numbers.

Number OUTPUT 6.013820134824E+18

Date OUTPUT : "1970-01-01" any date converstion
